# Eclipse: updates to referenced library .jar not picked up

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have 2 Java projects in my Eclipse workspace, as follows:

One is a library of code that automatically creates a .jar file whenever it builds.

The other is an application that uses classes in that library, and references the .jar file created by the library project (by right-clicking the app -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs...)

However, whenever I modify classes in my library project, although I can see that the library .jar gets updated, the app project doesn't pick up the changes unless I remove the library .jar from the app's referenced libraries and re-add it

Am I fundamentally doing something wrong? Is there perhaps a better way to connect an app to a shared library of code? How can I make sure my app will always refer to the latest library code?

Comment: Did you tried to link the library eclipse project instead of the Jar? Or maybe you have some constraints that does no allow you to do that?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by "link the library eclipse project instead of the Jar" - can you explain more?

Comment: In Build path menu, linking the project and not the Jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding it as a JAR dependency you could add it as a project dependency. Right click your project and go to properties. Click on 'Java Build Path' and select the 'Projects' tab.  Click 'Add..." and add your library project.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Eclipse (I'm sure it also worked the same with the ones before), doing a refresh and Clean on your library project then on your application will update the libraries referenced.

Comment: That doesn't really seem to help (I'm using Juno service release 2, if it's relevant). If, for example, I rename a method in a class in the library, refresh & clean the library, refresh & clean the app, the app doesn't pick up the new method name. If I expand the library reference in the app I can see the class in the referenced library still uses the old method name. If I remove the referenced library, then re-add it, the updated method name is picked up.

Comment: You can also quit Eclipse and restart. Not that I'm suggesting that this is a good solution, but it works.